# Find div with only 1 element with a particular class

Tags: jquery

What I need to do is match all elements which have 1 child which also has a particular class. I can already do it with:

```
$(this).children().length == 1 && $(this).children('.brclearer').length == 1
```

But is there a better/best way of doing it with jquery?

Comment: `if($(this).children('.brclearer').length)` This itself enough to do that.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest the following:

```
$('.brclearer:only-child').parent();
```

Which will find all elements with the class of `.brclearer` that are the only child of their respective parents and then select the parent element of those elements.

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:only-child`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#structural-pseudos).
- jQuery:

  - [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Comment: How can OP make a check by using the snippet provided by you? Like `$('.brclearer:only-child').parent().is(this)`  ?

Comment: I have to confess this looks good but I have copied/pasted it and it doesn't work. It looks like it should but it removes an element that doesn't even have the .brclearer class in it - whereas the original solution works fine?? I would love to mark this as the answer.

Comment: There's no mention of making "*a check*" in the question, only a request to "*match [relevant elements]*" . Antony, that seems incredibly unlikely; can you show a ("[mcve]") [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of this failure?

Comment: ok - valid point - this is used in an if statement to match/check the relevant element

Comment: Why are you using an if, when you can – with the above selector – simply select the elements you want? Leaving aside the report of an error (which again seems unlikely).

Comment: Because its part of a full if string: if (!$(this).hasClass('fullwidth') && ($(this).html().trim() == '' || $(this).children('.brclearer').length)){

Comment: Then show enough code to reproduce your actual problem, and explain the problem clearly. Please: take the time to post your "[mcve]" code to reproduce the problem, HTML, CSS and jQuery/JavaScript. Then, maybe, you might get better and more useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe can you search `.brclearer` element and then get parent, like this:

```
$('.brclearer').parent();
```

Or if you need `.brclearer` was only child use `only-child` selector

```
$('.brclearer:only-child').parent();
```